# Customise incoming call screen of device using Objective c

Tags: objective-c, webrtc, voip

Basically I want to provide a customised call screen which will have a view button instead of accept or reject button. So on tap of view button it will go inside the app for accept or reject order.

Is this really possible?

Comment: Use pushkit and local notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No. Apple will not allow you do anything with default call screen.** Some OS level access are not provided by apple. Android will give you all freedom to do anything with OS level features as well.